# Force all Local links in Laravel to open in HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I never coded in Laravel and one of my clients has a website built with Laravel that he recently switched to HTTPS.

The site open but all the images/videos/files open in HTTP and not HTTPS.

They use this format: /img/image.png instead of a full URL.

Any idea how to make it so that every single link/image/video opens in HTTPS?

The below is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>


RewriteEngine On

    #force https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

The website opens in HTTPS but some assets don't.

Comment: Don't need to do anything with Laravel - put the whole site under HTTPS (port 443) in the Apache httpd-vhosts.conf (or equivalent if you're using Nginx or whatever) and simply change the HTTP version (port 80) to a 301 redirect to the HTTPS version - that's what **should** be happening anyway with relative URLs if the site **is** under HTTPS.

Comment: are they using asset helper for the src?